# Is it possible for an artist to retain the rights to their artwork while also allowing the client to reproduce the artwork?

Tags: contract-law, intellectual-property, licensing

I'm designing an album cover for a client and they want the rights to put the album cover art on a multitude of items (posters, tshirts, etc).

Is there a way for the artist (me) to retain the rights to my work while giving the client limited rights to reproduce the art for any means of marketing the album? If so how would I word this in a contract?

Comment: "If so how would I word this in a contract?" This seems like a good situation to employ a lawyer to write the contract.

Comment: License agreements are not something you should try to write without a lawyer. I have a 600 page book on my bookshelf and another 200 page course pack that are limited to only a portion of the legal considerations that go into drafting licensing agreements. This is way over the head of an amateur if you want to do it even remotely right.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. This type of contract is called a license. Lawyers write them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this for a client, the client is paying you to do something for them, in other words they will own it.

If you want to do something different you need a contract, a complicated contract that needs a lawyer to draw up, then you and your client can do anything you want to agree to under the terms of the contract. Including you retaining ownership of the art if you can get your client to agree to that.